# Passing extras from notification with three Buttons to a service

Tags: android, notifications

I am trying to make a music player app. In notification i need three buttons . I am sending extras with the intent in notification. But somehow they never reach.
Here is my code
I think i need to discard previous extras somehow or change flag in pending intent not so sure.

```
   void showNotificationForeground() {

    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayerService.class);
    i.putExtra("name", name);
    i.putExtra("songname", songname);
    i.putExtra("isservice", true);

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0,
            i, 0);
    Intent ipause = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayerService.class);
    ipause.putExtra("name", name);
    ipause.putExtra("songname", songname);
    ipause.putExtra("isservice", true);
    ipause.putExtra("action", "pause");
    PendingIntent pipause = PendingIntent.getService(
            getApplicationContext(), 0, ipause, 0);
    Intent iplay = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayerService.class);
    iplay.putExtra("name", name);
    iplay.putExtra("songname", songname);
    iplay.putExtra("isservice", true);
    iplay.putExtra("action", "pause");
    PendingIntent piplay = PendingIntent.getService(
            getApplicationContext(), 0, iplay, 0);
    Intent istop = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayerService.class);
    istop.putExtra("name", name);
    istop.putExtra("songname", songname);
    istop.putExtra("isservice", true);
    istop.putExtra("action", "pause");
    PendingIntent pistop = PendingIntent.getService(
            getApplicationContext(), 0, istop, 0);
    //
    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("RajPlayer")
            .setContentText("Playing: " + songname)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContentIntent(pi)
            .addAction(R.drawable.play96, "Play", piplay)
            .addAction(R.drawable.pause96, "Pause", pipause)
            .addAction(R.drawable.cancel24, "Stop", pistop).build();
    //
    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, noti);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparison between intents does not take extras into account, as you can see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#filterEquals).

So what probably happens is that once the first pendingIntent is created android recycles it for all the following intents, because it believes they're identical - and since the first one doesn't have the action extra, you're not getting it.

The fastest way to verify that's the case is to give all your action intents an action, like so, just to differentiate them from one another.

```
ipause.setAction("justSomething");
iplay.setAction("toMakeTheIntents");
istop.setAction("NotEqual")
```

I believe this should solve your problem.

On a side note, you have the same action ("pause") for all your intents. Bad copy/paste probably. But it's not the issue, as you said you don't get the action at all.